# How to change weapons when using the PC keyboard?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I've got so far in the game that I have to use the pistol for training, however for some odd reason I can't use the HUD to change weapon types (it simply won't change the weapon when I release the button).

Has anyone ever had the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

The [manual](http://www.scribd.com/doc/44697421/Assassin-s-Creed-II-Manual) states that you can use the following keys to change weapons :

```
1 - Throwing Knives
2 - Hidden Blade
3 - Sword
4 - Fists
```

If that does not work you can use **Q** to get the weapon selector. If you have tried all this, then maybe you have run into some of the limitations for [the pistol](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Pistol).

According to [the wiki](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Pistol) the pistol will not work when in [**Secret Locations**](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Secret_Locations) levels.

Comment: The thing is that when I use the Q, it simply won't swich. I just obtained the pistol and have to use it to get farther in the game, but I cant. I can't use any items Medicine (1); Hidden Blades (2); Sword (3) and Hands (4). The weapon selector simply won't work.

Comment: "PISTOL: Select the pistol from the weapon wheel(Q) and lock(F) onto the target, then hold Left Click until the ray 
turns into a single sharp beam and release the button to shoot them." - Taken from AC2 FAQ, so it should work for you. I added keyboard shortcuts for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've probably forgotten this question by now, and yes, I'm a bit behind in the "gaming world".. But I figured this out by accident while playing so I wanted to share.

When you press and hold Q, you can select any weapon by *moving the freaking mouse* and then releasing Q. I have no idea why this isn't clarified anywhere in the game...

Answer (score 0):

go to control and change the inventory wheel i.e button 0
to any other keyword like 'u'.then return to game and press and hold u to select the desired weapon